# Stratified cross-validation in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am using the Apache Spark API in python, PySpark (--version 3.0.0), and would ideally like to perform cross-validation of my labelled data in a stratified manner since my data is highly imbalanced! I am currently using the below module.

```py
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator
```

In scikit-learn this is possible by defining a `StratifiedKFold` and placing it in the `cv` argument of any of the grid search function. This ensures that every K fold a given estimator is trained on, contains the labelled data in a proportionally representative way.

Is there an equivalent for this in PySpark?

< rant> I would have loved to asked this question from the Spark team or as an improvement suggestion but their [GitHub page](https://github.com/apache/spark) does not allow for either bug reports or improvement suggestions and their [official page](http://spark.apache.org/contributing.html) requires the accompanying source code suggestions, which is slightly above my skill set! </ rant>

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Spark ML doesn't supports Stratified cross-validation at the moment.

However, you could take a look at `spark-stratifier`. It's a Spark ML stratified cross validator component that was open sourced by HackerRank a few years ago [1]. You could take a look at that.

It can be installed by running `pip install spark-stratifier`.

Some example code to get you going:

```py
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from spark_stratifier import StratifiedCrossValidator

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()

data = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.1, 0.1])),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.0, -1.0])),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.3, 1.0])),
    (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.2, -0.5]))], ["label", "features"])

lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10)

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[lr])

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1, 0.01]) \
    .build()

scv = StratifiedCrossValidator(
        estimator=pipeline,
        estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
        evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
        numFolds=2
      )

model = scv.fit(data)
```

[1]: https://github.com/interviewstreet/spark-stratifier

Comment: Since I have written the code in PySpark 3.0.0 and installed all the relevant dependencies, the `spark-stratifier` does not seem to like it and throws a lengthy error relating to `Py4JError`. It also doesn't work when I reinstall PySpark 3.0.0